# Why does not the result in this notes show P is not NP in BSS model?

Tags: complexity-theory, computation-models

As far as I know (not understand that well though) BSS model is a real computation model and $P_{\Bbb R}\neq NP_{\Bbb R}$ is a real analog of $P\neq NP$ problem in BSS model.

The lecture notes http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~janos/COURSES/ESSLLI-2014/E-abelian.pdf show $P_G\neq NP_G$ at every infinite abelian group $G$.

Each of $\Bbb Z$, $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$ is an example of such $G$.

So why does this not settle the $P$ and $NP$ problem in BSS model?

Comment: These results are for unordered groups. The usual model is for ordered groups. At least that's what the slides seem to imply.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thank you very much I saw that too but I do not understand the nuances very well. May be you can provide a clearer picture in an elementary way? does the unordered nature provide a strengthening of model? I could not find lecture notes (only slides were there).

Comment: My guess is that in the ordered versions you're allowed to compare variables.